# What is the point of "static new" modifier for a function?

Tags: c#, static, new-operator, modifier

Today, I found something in legacy code. It has "static new" for one function. It looks like this.

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.Do");
    }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    public static new void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar.Do");
    }
}
```

I don't understand the ***static new*** modifier for the **Do** method in class **Bar**. In C#, static method can only be invoked with class name instead of object name. So, I don't think there is any difference between having the "new" and not.

Generally, if some syntax is unnecessary, C# just treat it is error.
Anybody has any idea about why C# allows such syntax?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you remove the **new** from your code you get:

> warning CS0108: 'Bar.Do()' hides inherited member 'Foo.Do()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

The C# compiler just warns you that you might be doing something you did not intend and asks you to insert the **new** keyword to confirm that you know what you are doing. Besides suppressing the warning, it has no other effects.

Comment: while it only suppresses the warning, it makes the intention explicit (to avoid any confusion), check my answer

Comment: Also check documentation of the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier).

Answer (score 16):

That applies only for external callers. Remember that you can call a static method of the base class, so something like this is valid:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Do() { Console.WriteLine("Foo.Do"); }
}
class Bar : Foo // :Foo added
{
    public static void Something()
    {
        Do();
    }
}
```

This is why the warning tells you to put the new, you want to avoid any confusion when doing this:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Do() { Console.WriteLine("Foo.Do"); }
}
class Bar : Foo // :Foo added
{
    public static void Something()
    {
        Do();
    }
    public static new void Do() { Console.WriteLine("Bar.Do"); }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

> ```
> public class BaseC
> {
>     public static int x = 55;
>     public static int y = 22;
> }
>
> public class DerivedC : BaseC
> {
>     // Hide field 'x'.
>     new public static int x = 100;
>
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         // Display the new value of x:
>         Console.WriteLine(x);
>
>         // Display the hidden value of x:
>         Console.WriteLine(BaseC.x);
>
>         // Display the unhidden member y:
>         Console.WriteLine(y);
>     }
> }
> /*
> Output:
> 100
> 55
> 22
> */
> ```

Your example, to make it clear, should be

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void Do() {}
}
public class Bar :Foo
{
    public new static void Do() {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the second class Bar doesn't seem to inherit from Foo. This seems to be a typo because it doesn't makes sense otherwise.

Assuming it to be a typo, the "new" modifier explicitly hides the base class version of the function `Do()`.  This means that the derived version of the `Do()` method effectively replaces the base class version.

Using "new" here documents the fact that the inherited method is intended as a replacement for the base class version of `Do()`.

For more information, see [new Modifier (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Here's the updated documentation of the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier).